# Finding a system of equations of which solution is a span

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

The question is how to find a system of equations when I have the solution. The solution is subspace: $\operatorname{span}\{(2,4,-6), (4,8,-10)\}$.

I can see they describe a plane, however, the equation that describes this plane omits the last variable and looks like this: $$8x - 4y = 0.$$

Doesn't this mean that the solution to this is from $\mathbb{R}^2$ and not $\mathbb{R}^3$? So it would look like this $\{(1,2)\}$?
It is just a technical question if it's okay to just add a dimension.

It seems to be a bit odd. Could I add to the original solution a zero for example? $\operatorname{span}\{(2,4,-6,0)(4,8,-10,0)\}.$
Sorry for the English.

Comment: $z$ is free to roam.  Anything of the form $ax+by+cz=d$ describes a plane in $3$-space.  In particular, $c$ can be zero.

Comment: Other than the degenerate case $(a,b,c)=(0,0,0)$, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a plane. A plane is described by one equation in three unknowns.

$(2,4,-6)\times(2,4,-10)=\begin{vmatrix}i&j&k\\2&4&-6\\2&4&-10\end{vmatrix}=-16i+8j$ to get $-16x+8y=0$, for the equation (up to scalar multiple).

Answer (score 1):

The two vectors span a plane.  You want to find a vector that is perpendicular to both so it is perpendicular to the plane, then write an equation that says the dot product of a vector with this perpendicular is $0$.  What do you know about finding a vector that is perpendicular to two others in three space?

Comment: Not much to be honest.

Comment: Have you heard of the cross product?

Comment: No I have not, or at least I think I have not.

Comment: If you look it up in Wikipedia the first few sentences talk about what it is and why it helps you.

Comment: thank you very much